# Get photos of people you aren't friends with in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

When you have an access token it's easy enough to get the photos of friends (with appropriate permissions), however I want to get all available photos of everyone in a facebook group.  I therefore have a list of facebook IDs of people who I may or may not be friends with.

To summarize 100001448205991 is a user completely at random who I don't know and am not friends with, but they have lots of publicly visible photos, however the following query doesn't produce any results:
https://graph.facebook.com/100001448205991/photos?access_token=[MyUser'sAccessToken]

Is there a way to get these photos using the facebook api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get this information from the graph api if you are not friends with this user.  You would have to scrape it with a logged in Facebook cookie with this format of URL:
[https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=**profileId**&sk=photos](https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=%2a%2aprofileId%2a%2a&sk=photos), with this obviously being against Facebook's terms of service.

Answer (score 1):

no, to get the photos for a user via graph api / fql, you need to have the corresponding permission

Comment: The question is whether there's a permission you can obtain to allow access to public content

Comment: no, this cannot be done..... no matter what perm you get  / set for a user.... you just cannot get photos for another "random" user that is not even the current user's friends

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a 200px wide profile picture.

http://graph.facebook.com/USERID/picture?type=large

Comment: +1 Thanks, though not ideal (only gets one photo), it's at least better than nothing

Comment: that only gives the user's profile pic, not the photos in his album